# rewriting url to hide real page path

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I recently with the help of SO solved my htaccess rewriterule issue:

[Reuse subdomain in a rewrite rule](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14062575/1291428)

The result is that when somebody enters

```
whatever.example.com/anypage
```

in the adress bar, the htaccess automatically redirects to

```
whatever.example.com/somepath/whatever/anypage
```

What I wish to do is to find a way to just show `whatever.example.com/anypage` in the adress bar with the content of `whatever.example.com/somepath/whatever/anypage` displayed.

In the post I mentioned earlier, Jon Lin clearly mentions the following:

> redirects always change what's in the browser's URL address bar

However I know some very frequent cases of url rewritting that would show in the adress bar let's say, for instance:

```
example.com/article-1-15
```

but actually showing the content of

```
example.com/somepath/somepage.php?article=1&otherparam=15
```

How could this apply to my case? I really wish to have a tiny url but it seems I missed something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/([^/]+)$
RewriteRule .*  http://whatever.example.com/somepath/whatever/%1 [L]
```

It will map:

`http://whatever.example.com/anypage`

To a resource at:

`http://whatever.example.com/somepath/whatever/anypage`

showing always in the browser's address bar:

`http://whatever.example.com/anypage`

**UPDATED**

If whatever is dynamic and is the same in the substitution URI, here is another option:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ([^/]+)\.example\.com.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/([^/]+)$
RewriteRule .*  http://%1.example.com/somepath/%1/%2 [L]
```

This will work as long as both "whatever" in the substitution path are the same. If they are not, the last "whatever" has to be hardcoded, like this:

```
RewriteRule .*  http://%1.example.com/somepath/whatever/%2 [L]
```

There is no other way as the incoming URL doesn't have it.

Comment: "whatever" is dynamic, are you sure your htaccess would do it?

Comment: Well, the only way to be sure it does what you need is testing it.

Comment: can't you see your htaccess will never handle dynamic subdomains? Maybe I am mistaken but it seems pretty obvious since you're hardcoding it in the rewriterule

Comment: What the rule is trying to do is to keep the last folder `/anypage` as last folder. That's all, so the names of the folders or subdomains are not important.

Comment: @Sebas I understand what you said in your comment, so I updated my answer. I did not see it that way from your question.

Comment: the %1 is replaced by index.php (i'm asking for si.php page, so it must be a default directoryindex from my php.ini) and the subdomain name disappears from url. No trace of "si.php" either, that should go at the end instead of %2 if I understood well your rewriterule.

Comment: The `%1` is the "whatever" subdomain in the requested URI `http://whatever.example.com/anypage` and the `%2` is the "anypage" folder in the same URI.

Comment: `http://testacc.example.com/si.php` redirects to `http://index.php.example.com/path/index.php/`

Comment: There is no index.php in the rules in my answer, so it can't be redirecting to the URI in your comment because of my rules. I tested it and got: `http://testacc.example.com/si.php` is redirected to `http://testacc.example.com/somepath/testacc/si.php`, which is what you describe in your question.

Comment: damnit, my server must have something preventing it to run

Comment: You can always test it [here](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/), but maybe is the script si.php that is redirecting to `http://index.php.example.com/path/index.php/`.

Comment: Just in case, it is a silent redirection as you asked, so the substitution URI doesn't show in the browser's address bar. To show it, `R=301` has to be added to the flag **L** in the rule.

Comment: Suppose I Have URL Like www.admin.com/23445.zip
which will automatically redirect to www.admin.com/files/23445.zip

where 23445 will be dynamically 
..what will be the rule then?