# htaccess: subdomain to folder on server. Keep URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I need help with (internal redirecting?) using apache's htaccess.

On my server i have a *main domain*:

**url**: domain.com
**server-path**: /opt/public_html/domain.com/

and a *subdomain*:

**url**: sub.domain.com
**server-path**: /opt/public_html/sub.domain.com/

When a visitor types `sub.domain.com` i want the URL to be unchanged. I also want the server to serve the file `/opt/public_html/domain.com/index.php` to the visitor. How do i do this in .htaccess?

Also, if the visitor types `sub.domain.com/sofa/` the server should serve the file  `/opt/public_html/domain.com/sofa/index.php` without changing the URL.

Got it? OK last example:

If visitor types `sub.domain.com/?big=mac` the server should show the file `/opt/public_html/domain.com/?big=mac` without changing the URL.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Sorry? so visiting `http://sub.domain.com` goes to `/public_html/sub.domain.com/`, while `http://sub.domain.com/sofa` goes to `/public_html/domain.com/sofa/index.php`? This is weird!

Comment: No. If `http://sub.domain.com` then `/public_html/domain.com/` and if `http://sub.domain.com/sofa` then `/public_html/domain.com/sofa/index.php` (or `/public_html/domain.com/sofa/` doesn't matter)

Comment: But in your question you didn't say like that?

Comment: No. Right now http://sub.domain.com goes to /public_html/sub.domain.com/ Instead i want http://sub.domain.com to go to /public_html/domain.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you enable `RewriteEngine` In your .htaccess, you should be able to create a condition and rule to handle serving the main domain's pages at the subdomain URL. Something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} sub.domain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sub.domain.com
RewriteRule .* domain.com/%1 [L]
```

The `RewriteCond` line makes the rule apply to any page at sub.domain.com and should be served from `public_html/sub.domain.com`. It should (hopefully internally) change the URI to `http://domain.com/whatever` without changing it in the browser.

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642426/htaccess-rewrite-subdomain-to-directory) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070635/rewritting-url-to-hide-real-page-path) for similar information. If .htaccess is really not working for you, you could try a proxy, `mod_rewrite`, or creating symlinks.