# Hide a href URL in web browser

Tags: java, html, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm developing small web application to give access to a URL for authorised users.

After validating the URL, I'm providing the two hyperlinks like Reports and Logout. This is the code.

```
<a href ="http://hostname.com/reports/users">Reports</a>
<a href="LogoutServlet">Logout</a>
```

Here the question is the time user click on Reports link, its giving the href link as it is in web browser like `http://hostname.com/reports/users`
Expected output should be like `http://hostname.com/Somethingelse`

**Update Question:**

To hide real folder path i.e  `http://hostname.com/reports/users` am using .htaccess. I have kept this file under WEB-INF folder, can anyone please hep me how to form RewriteRule and RewriteCond in .htaccess file. This is the file I have tried. If .htaccess is invoking and if it is wrong how come still its going to same folder the time I click on Reports link. This is the .htaccess I have tried

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^\.]+).hostname.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://hostname.com/reports/users [L]
```

Comment: you can do it with .htaccess https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070635/rewriting-url-to-hide-real-page-path

Comment: Thanks for comment @Ifaruki, .htaccess is a third party library. Is it possible to do the same within html?

Answer (score 0):

This way you can customize the servlet mapping pattern

```
@WebServlet("/reports/users")
public class LogoutServlet extends HttpServlet {
//
}
```

See https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebServlet.html